# Парсинг(Скрапинг) web-стриниц

Tags: java, парсер, web-scraping

Мне нужно пропарсить веб страницу в java, на которой необходимо сперва залогиниться ввести пароль и тд. Читал в интернете , это делают через htmlunit.WebClient , но конкретно понятного примера не нашел. 
Может кто имел опыт работы с чем-то подобным и подскажет ,куда двигаться , какие библиотеки необходимы или мб скинет туториал .
Hope for your Support !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте Selenium Web Driver. Вам понадобится сам селениум, один из драйверов для браузера и сам браузер (популярные решения хром либо мазила). Насчет htmlunit - у него проблема с js-скриптами и соответственно возникают проблемы с сайтами, которые содержат динамический контент.
Пример вытягивания страницы с помощью селениума и хрома в фоновом процессе (без  отображения окна браузера):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--headless");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("http://yourURL:8080/#/login);
    WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("userId"));
    WebElement psw = driver.findElement(By.id("userPsw"));
    username.sendKeys("myLogin");
    psw.sendKeys("myPsw");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicityWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //or
    //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.persenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("someCssExpected")));
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Войти")).click();
    System.out.println("Page source: " + driver.getPageSource());
}
```

Comment: Получилось !! Весьма Благодарен!